# How to create python package that can invoke as command?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

I am building a python package with *setuptools* and I am able to make it successfully, but for importing the module I need a python3 interpreter. But I want to use this python package as a command line tool like we have awscli, we install awscli with pip but we can use the aws command from the Linux terminal.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

TIA

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+scripts+entry_points

Comment: You need `scripts` or `entry_points` in your `setup.py`/`setup.cfg`. See the docs: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#scripts , https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html